# ORA-01013 timeouts on unrelated queries while indexing a large table

Tags: hibernate, indexing, oracle11g, timeout, sqlplus

I'm seeing large blocks of ORA-01013 timeouts occur whenever I'm attempting to index a large table in Oracle. Many timeouts come in over a roughly two second period. *This happens consistently every time the indexes run.*

The timeouts are occurring on random transactions/queries that are *unrelated to the table being indexed.* For some background, this is a 24/7 transaction system which is where all the "random" transactions are coming from.

Furthermore, the table being indexed is not being actively used or accessed in any way while it is being loaded and indexed (we have two copies of the table that are swapped via synonyms after the load and index are complete).

It seems like the database is hitting a resource bottleneck which is causing other processes to timeout, but that's just a guess.

More specifically, I've seen the timeouts pop up during two different indexes on the *same* table below. Just to reiterate, the timeouts are on queries completely unrelated to this table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### Env info

```
DB: Oracle 11g
Load and index operations are executed using sqlplus.
JBoss6/hibernate is where the timing-out-queries originate from.
```

#### Index statements that cause the timeouts:

```
create index INFO_TB_IX2 on INFO_TB (RISK_ID);
create index INFO_TB_IX4 on INFO_TB (ACCOUNT_NBR);
```

#### Table info:

```
Name: INFO_TB

Average records loaded: Just under 300 million

PK: (ACCOUNT_ID,PORTFOLIO)

Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------------
RISK_ID                                            NUMBER
ACCOUNT_ID                                NOT NULL NUMBER
ACCOUNT_NBR                               NOT NULL NUMBER
PORTFOLIO                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
PORTFOLIO_ID                              NOT NULL NUMBER
```

Comment: Why do you think the indexing is the cause of these timeouts? The fact it's a co-incidence and has happened twice? You'd be better off looking at the timeout thresholds and running a stats pack around when these timeouts occur. Yes it might be an overall lack of resources, but perhaps your thresholds are set too low, to allow for instances when an intensive query is being executed.

Comment: @bob This happens consistently every time this index process runs. I've checked the statistics and couldn't find anything conclusive. What thresholds are you referring to exactly?

Comment: I presume you have some set timeout threshold within your app along the lines of 'no response < 2000msec cancel'. Have you checked the stats and looked at cpu usage etc. when this index rebuild is taking place? The server itself may be taking a big hit, and the index rebuild taking all available memory (or at least enough to appreciatively degrade all other queries). What index rebuild is taking place? Would gathering stats not work instead?

Comment: @bob That sounds right to me. We had some statistics pulled again today and it does look like the CPU is getting pegged pretty hard. I'm thinking it's because the tablespace the indexes are being created in is nearly full which is resulting in thrashing and high CPU usage. Which would be slowing everything else down like you're saying.

As for the timeouts themselves, yes the applicates has a 4000 ms timeout setting.